# Tablesorter specific sort with french number

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, tablesorter

I'm using tablesorter for sort different type of number and string, but in this number i have number like : (with commas and space)

```
200,08€
1 201,56€
1 521 120,00€
```

I must be sort like

```
1 521 120,00€
1 201,56€
200,08€
```

and inverse.

I try a parser :

```js
$.tablesorter.addParser({
  id: "colcpl",
  is: function(s) {
    return /^[0-9]?[0-9, \.]*$/.test(s);
  },
  format: function(s) {
    return jQuery.tablesorter.formatFloat(s.replace(/,/g, ''));
  },
  type: "numeric"
});
```

but it doesn't work, have you an idea of why ? 
thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with the parser: (1) The comma should be replaced with a decimal point, and (2) the spaces need to be removed.

Try this update ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/1675/))

```
$(function() {

  $.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: "colcpl",
    is: function(s) {
      return /^[0-9]?[0-9, \.]*$/.test(s);
    },
    format: function(s) {
      return jQuery.tablesorter.formatFloat(s.replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/,/g, '.'));
    },
    type: "numeric"
  });

  $('table').tablesorter({
    sortList: [[0,1]],
    headers: {
      0: { sorter: 'colcpl' }
    }
  });

});
```